# Sorting array elements based on user inputs

Tags: python, arrays

Sorting user inputs based on categories that the inputs fall into and then displaying the # of times the input is in those categories.

```
    if tempCelcius <= 20:   #counts the number of Cool days in list
        x
    elif tempCelcius >= 21 and tempC <= 30:  #counts the number of Warm days in list
        y
    elif tempCelcius >= 31:  #counts number of Hot days in list
        z =
print ('# of Cool days: ', x)
print ('# of Warm days: ', y)
print ('# of Hot  days: ', z)
```

Comment: Iterate the list of temps you have. And move the if condition to inside that iteration, and increase the variables amount (x,y,z) when the If condition succeed. then print those variables,

Comment: what do you mean by iterate the list of temps?

Comment: list of temperatures.

Comment: I know you meant the temperatures haha

Comment: i edited my program. I am unsure of what variable I need to call in order for the IF to sort through the list as well as how to add the counting of each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to get the length of the each temperature range.

```
temps = ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6', 'Day 7', 'Day 8', 'Day 9', 'Day 10']
celList = []
fahList = []
for temp in temps:
    print ('What was the temp on', temp)
    tempCelcius = int(input(' '))
    fah = round((tempCelcius * 1.8) + 32)
    celList.append(tempCelcius)
    fahList.append(fah)

x =  len([t for t in celList if t <= 20])        #counts number of cool days within the 10 temps
y =  len([t for t in celList if 21 <= t <= 30])  #counts number of warm days within the 10 temps
z =  len([t for t in celList if t >= 31])        #counts number of Hot days within the 10 temps

print("Cool days", x)
print("Warm days", y)
print("Hot days", z)
```

Output

```
What was the temp on Day 1
 6
What was the temp on Day 2
 6
What was the temp on Day 3
 6
What was the temp on Day 4
 99
What was the temp on Day 5
 99
What was the temp on Day 6
 99
What was the temp on Day 7
 23
What was the temp on Day 8
 23
What was the temp on Day 9
 23
What was the temp on Day 10
 23
Cool days 3
Warm days 4
Hot days 3
```

Comment: For my better understand:
the `len` function returns the number of items in the list therefore, it does the counting by itself? I know that is a very under explained way, I am still very new at this. I just want to make sure I understand what you did so I can apply it in the future.